# Refactoring code to have base class with just a member common

Tags: c#, oop, base-class

```
public class AStreamManager
{
    public IVehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    public string AIp { get; set; }
    public int APort { get; set; }

    public delegate NetworkStream ConnectToAStream(string host, int port);

    public AStreamManager(IVehicle vehicle, string IP, int Port)
    {
        Vehicle = vehicle;

        AIp = IP;
        APort = Port;
    }

    public NetworkStream ConnectToVehicleAStream(ConnectToAStream conn)
    {
        return conn(AIp, APort); ;
    }
}

public class BStreamManager
{
    public IVehicle Vehicle { get; set; }

    public string BIp { get; set; }
    public int BPort { get; set; }

    public delegate NetworkStream ConnectToBStream(string host, int port);

    public BStreamManager(IVehicle vehicle, string IP, int Port)
    {
        Vehicle = vehicle;

        BIp = IP;
        BPort = Port;
    }

    public NetworkStream ConnectToVehicleBStream(ConnectToBStream conn)
    {
        return conn(BIp, BPort); ;
    }
```

}

I have two classes `AStreamManager` and `BStreamManager`. As you can see above,there is a member variable `Vehicle` of type `IVehicle` which is common across these classes.
Does it make sense and can I  refactor in such a way that 'IVehicle Vehicle` is moved to a base class?

Comment: The classes are identical. Why do you have two of them? You can "refactor" them into a single `StreamManager` class, and then instantiate one for AStream and another for BStream? `var aStream = new StreamManager(); var bStream = new StreamManager;`

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, you can move Vehicle to a base class.  Anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems very hypothetical to me. Looking at your classes, I can't really see a reason for their existence at all. You have `AIp` and `BIp` but these are clearly IP addresses, so it makes no sense to have two different properties. I'd simply have a `StreamManager` class and that's that.